# how to convert .txt into .xls in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, parsing

```
with open(output_filename, 'w') as f_output:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory): 
        for filename in filenames:
             if filename.startswith('VCALogParser_output'): 
                cur_file = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                with open(cur_file, "r") as f_input:
                    f_input.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
                    backup = min(back_up , f_input.tell())
                    f_input.seek(-backup, os.SEEK_END)
                    last_lines = ''.join(f_input.readlines()[-6:])
                    try:
                        summary = ', '.join(re.search(r'(\d+ warning\(s\)).*?(\d+ error\(s\)).*?(\d+ scenarios\(s\) FAILED)', last_lines, re.S).groups())
                    except AttributeError:
                        summary = "VCA DID NOT START"
                    f_output.write('{}: {}\n'.format(filename, summary))
```

The above code is parsing through a file and reading some data from the file and putting that as an output in the form of .txt. but I want to ouput that as a .xls. Can anyone tell me how to convert the below .txt to .xls?

output in .txt form :

```
VCALogParser_output_ARW.log: 12 warning(s), 85 error(s), 32 scenarios(s) FAILED
VCALogParser_output_CZC.log: 18 warning(s), 33 error(s), 14 scenarios(s) FAILED
VCALogParser_output_DUN.log: VCA DID NOT START
VCALogParser_output_FRC.log: 12 warning(s), 34 error(s), 12 scenarios(s) FAILED
VCALogParser_output_GED.log: 39 warning(s), 79 error(s), 27 scenarios(s) FAILED
VCALogParser_output_MNT.log: 41 warning(s), 76 error(s), 33 scenarios(s) FAILED
VCALogParser_output_NON.log: 25 warning(s), 50 error(s), 14 scenarios(s) FAILED
VCALogParser_output_PTB.log: VCA DID NOT START
VCALogParser_output_PTP.log: 31 warning(s), 35 error(s), 21 scenarios(s) FAILED
VCALogParser_output_SPM.log: 58 warning(s), 150 error(s), 57 scenarios(s) FAILED
VCALogParser_output_SWS.log: 14 warning(s), 23 error(s), 11 scenarios(s) FAILED
```

Answer (score 1):

try [xlutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils) module

"Utilities for working with Excel files that require both xlrd and xlwt"

Comment: how to install the xlrd and xlwt ? I tried to install using these commands - pip install, easy install and so on but windows prompt is saying it as an un recognized command.

Comment: download the tar.gz here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt, then decompress it and in a terminal type `python setup.py install` in the decompressed directory

Comment: i am getting the error as : PS C:\Python27_3> python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from xlwt import __VERSION__
ImportError: No module named xlwt

Comment: Have you successfully downloaded https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlwt/xlwt-1.0.0.tar.gz#md5=5e5e4eae8fe7ee3d43f9324767ad925e ? Then, you must decompress it and type the python command in **xlwt-1.0.0 directory** where setup.py file is located